# Показ картинки на весь экран устройства

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

У меня есть ссылка на картинку и мне нужно показать эту картинку во весь экран iphone.
У меня так :

```
  NSString *url = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
  NSString *title = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
  WebViewController *vc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url title:title];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Но такой вариант не подходит.
В общем, нужно просто отобразить картинку в экране, зная ссылку на нее ( url ). Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Сделал так:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // NSString *url = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
//NSString *title = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
//WebViewController *vc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url title:title];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png"]];
UIImageView *ourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
[ourImageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[controller setView:ourImageView];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Но почему то ничего не происходит...

Comment: выведи  NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);
У меня подозрение, что он у тебя не инициализирован.
Что в console пишет?

Comment: а как в консоле смотреть? я добавил эту строчку  NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController); после [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; 

Когда нажимаю run и перехожу на отображение картинки, то в коде флажок устанавливается на строчке UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; и пишет слева Thread 1,breakpoint 1.1

Comment: добавил )))

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/77yqayhiyf731hz/x001_EmptyTestIOS.zip
Сдесь я все зделал, чтобы в tableView отображалась изображение на весь екран. Вот тебе пример, разбирайся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png"]];
UIImageView *ourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
[ourImageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[controller setView:ourImageView];
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: а чем вы рекомендуете проинициализировать
`navigationController` просто   `UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];` ? или как-то по другому? А то я всё сделал как вы сказали, а что-то изображение поверх не рисуется.